# Ordenar matrices por valor medio obtenido

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Estoy trabajando con OpenCV, Python y Numpy.

Separé los componentes verde, rojo y azul de una imagen RGB con OpenCV y Python. Luego subdivide cada una de estas matrices en submatrices 8x8 para trabajar con ellas. Hasta ahora, esto ya está hecho.

De cada una de las submatrices 8x8 que genere, necesito obtener la media de cada una y ordenar las matrices en orden descendente según la media obtenida. Para obtener la media estoy usando Numpy pero me encuentro atrapado en esto, ya que no entiendo muy bien como ordenar las matrices en orden descendente, según la media obtenida.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("6.jpg")
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)


def sub_matrices(color_channel):
   matrices = []

   for i in range(int(color_channel.shape[0]/8)):
       for j in range(int(color_channel.shape[1]/8)):
           matrices.append(color_channel[i*8:i*8 + 8, j*8:j*8+8])
   return matrices

#returns list of sub matrices
r_submatrices = sub_matrices(r)
g_submatrices = sub_matrices(g)
b_submatrices = sub_matrices(b)

print (r_submatrices)
print (g_submatrices)
print (b_submatrices)
```

Necesito ayuda con eso.

Answer (score 2):

Como tienes las matrices en listas, puedes usar el método `sort` que la lista provee junto con el argumento `key` del mismo.

El ordenamiento sería:

```py
import numpy as np

r_submatrices.sort(key=np.mean)
```

Ten en cuenta que ese ordenamiento es *inplace*. Usando el argumento `key`, en lugar de usar el valor de los elementos de la lista, utilizarás el valor que resulta de aplicar la función---en este caso np.mean---a cada elemento de la lista.

También puedes utilizar `sorted`:

```py
import numpy as np

r_ordenadas = sorted(r_submatrices, key=np.mean)
```